# merge 2 maps Map<Enum, Map<String,Object>> in java

Tags: java, hashmap

i have 2 HashMaps

```
Map<ProductType, Map<String, Product>> map1;
Map<ProductType, Map<String, Product>> map2;

class Product {
private string id; // a unique key of 32 digit alpha numberic charaters
}

map1 --> "Type1" : {{"P1":"423432423"},{"P2":"tertertr35432"}}
map2 --> "Type1" : {{"P3":"423467865832423"},{"P4":"tert89789ertr35432"}}
         "Type2" : {{"P5":"4978965832423"}}

result -> "Type1" : {{"P1":"423432423"},{"P2":"tertertr35432"},{"P3":"423467865832423"},{"P4":"tert89789ertr35432"}}
           Type2" : {{"P5":"4978965832423"}}
```

I tried putAll() but that's overriding the values.

Comment: What's ProductType?

Comment: can you explain on what you meant by overriding the values. Also, can you share what's your expectation here. Additionally, it would be great if you put in your putAll code

Comment: please share real code, running a simplified scenario.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero The question title says it's an `enum`.

Comment: @MagusVerma The expectation is already in the question, see the `result`.

Comment: @rkosegi The `result` shown in the question already defines what "merge" means, and it is not a `Multimap`.

Comment: By the way, if that id of “32 digit alpha numberic characters” is actually the hexadecimal representation of a 128-bit [UUID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), you should know that Java provides a [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You do use `putAll()`, but on the inner map, not the outer map.

The following implementation does not require Java 8.

```java
Map<ProductType, Map<String, Product>> map3 = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<ProductType, Map<String, Product>> e : map1.entrySet())
    map3.put(e.getKey(), new HashMap<>(e.getValue())); // Copy inner map
for (Map.Entry<ProductType, Map<String, Product>> e : map2.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Product> inner = map3.get(e.getKey());
    if (inner == null)
        map3.put(e.getKey(), new HashMap<>(e.getValue())); // Copy inner map
    else
        inner.putAll(e.getValue()); // Merge inner maps
}
```

In case of duplicate Products, the `Product` from `map2` will win.